# SMTP compile error

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, smtp

i have this code for SMTP with login authentication, i'm trying to compile it under Ubuntu 13.04

but I'm getting a compiler error when trying to compile the program with g++ -o command line

```
mailogin.cpp: In function ‘bool smtp_send(std::string, int, std::string, std::string, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, std::string, std::string, std::string)’:
mailogin.cpp:148:17: error: ‘login_name’ was not declared in this scope
mailogin.cpp:148:37: error: ‘login_pass’ was not declared in this scope
mailogin.cpp:150:34: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
mailogin.cpp:152:61: error: ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope
mailogin.cpp:190:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
mailogin.cpp:190:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
mailogin.cpp:190:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
mailogin.cpp:190:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
mailogin.cpp:190:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
mailogin.cpp:190:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

can someone help me?

this is my code

```
#include <string>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

#define safe_send( sd, b ) if( sd_write(sd, b) <= 0 ){ close(sd); return false; }
#define safe_read( sd, b ) if( (buffer = sd_read(sd)) == "" ){ \
                               close(sd); return false; \
                           } \
                           else if( buffer.find("220") == string::npos && \
                                    buffer.find("235") == string::npos && \
                                    buffer.find("250") == string::npos && \
                                    buffer.find("334") == string::npos && \
                                    buffer.find("354") == string::npos ){ \
                                    printf( "WARNING: %s\n", buffer.c_str() ); \

int sd_create( char *host, int port ){
    int sd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

    if( sd <= 0 ){
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    hostent * resol = gethostbyname( host );
    if( resol ){
        bzero( &server, sizeof(server) );
        server.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port        = htons(port);
        bcopy( resol->h_addr, &(server.sin_addr.s_addr), resol->h_length );
    }

    if( connect( sd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server) ) != 0 ){
        return -1;
    }

    return sd;
}

string sd_read( int sd ){
    string buffer("");
    unsigned char c;
    bool isEOL(false), isEOF(false);

    while( !isEOL && !isEOF ){
        if( recv( sd, &c, sizeof(unsigned char), 0 ) < 1 ){
            isEOF = true;
        }
        else if( c == '\n' ){
            isEOL = true;
        }
        else if( c != '\r' ){
            buffer += c;
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}

int sd_write( int sd, string buffer ){
    return write( sd, buffer.c_str(), buffer.size() );
}

string base64( unsigned char *data, unsigned int size ){
    static const char b64_charset[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    string ret;
    unsigned char block_3[3];
    unsigned char block_4[4];
    unsigned char * str = data;
    int i = 0,
        j = 0;

    while( size-- ){
        block_3[i++] = *(str++);
        if( i == 3 ){
            block_4[0] = (block_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
            block_4[1] = ((block_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((block_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
            block_4[2] = ((block_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((block_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
            block_4[3] = block_3[2] & 0x3f;

            for(i = 0; (i <4) ; i++){
                ret += b64_charset[block_4[i]];
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if(i){
        for(j = i; j < 3; j++){
            block_3[j] = '\0';
        }
        block_4[0] = (block_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
        block_4[1] = ((block_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((block_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
        block_4[2] = ((block_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((block_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
        block_4[3] = block_3[2] & 0x3f;

        for(j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++){
            ret += b64_charset[block_4[j]];
        }
        while((i++ < 3)){
            ret += '=';
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

bool smtp_send( string server_name, int port, string from, string subject, vector<string> receivers, string message, string login, string password )
{
    int i, j, sd;
    string buffer("");

    sd = sd_create( (char *)server_name.c_str(), port );
    if ( sd == -1 ){
        return false;
    }

    safe_send( sd, "EHLO emoticode_mailer\r\n" );

    // read until last '250 .*' reached
    while( (buffer = sd_read(sd)) != "" ){
        if( buffer.find("220") == string::npos &&
            buffer.find("235") == string::npos &&
            buffer.find("250") == string::npos &&
            buffer.find("334") == string::npos &&
            buffer.find("354") == string::npos ){

            printf( "WARNING: %s\n", buffer.c_str() );
        }
        else if( buffer.find( "250 " ) != string::npos ){
            break;
        }
    }

    int auth_len = login_name.size() + login_pass.size() + 2;
    unsigned char * b64auth = new unsigned char[auth_len];
    memset( b64auth, 0x00, auth_len );

    memcpy( &b64auth[1], login_name.c_str(), login_name.size() );
    memcpy( &b64auth[2 + login_name.size()], login_pass.c_str(), login_pass.size() );

    string hash = base64( b64auth, auth_len );

    delete [] b64auth;

    safe_send( sd, "AUTH PLAIN " + hash + "\r\n" );
    safe_read( sd, buffer );

    safe_send( sd, "MAIL FROM: <" + from + ">\r\n" );
    safe_read( sd, buffer );
    for( i = 0; i < receivers.size(); ++i ){
        safe_send( sd, "RCPT TO: <" + receivers[i] + ">\r\n" );
        safe_read( sd, buffer );
    }
    safe_send( sd, "DATA\r\n" );
    safe_read( sd, buffer );

    safe_send( sd, "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n" );
    safe_send( sd, "From: <" + from + ">\r\n" );
    safe_send( sd, "To: <" + receivers[0] + ">\r\n" );
    safe_send( sd, "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" );
    safe_send( sd, "Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n" );
    safe_send( sd, "X-Mailer: Emoticode smtp_send\r\n" );
    safe_send( sd, "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" );

    safe_send( sd, message );

    safe_send( sd, "\r\n.\r\n" );
    safe_read( sd, buffer );
    safe_send( sd, "RSET\r\n" );
    safe_read( sd, buffer );
    safe_send( sd, "QUIT\r\n" );

    close(sd);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the corresponding code? It's hard to tell what is going wrong from the error messages alone.

Comment: i've just post my quotes, thx mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare `login_name` and `login_pass`. Shouldn't that be `login` and `password` which you pass to the function `smtp_send` as arguments?